# Electron beginner, how to read file from menu to html?

Tags: javascript, electron

I create a simple electron project, create a Menu, for open file, everything is fine until I got data from file. I found there is no `document` or `$` object, how can I passing data to DOM, like `p` textContext?

```
dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}, (filePath) => {
        // read the file
        fs.readFile(filePath[0], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                // do something
            } else {
                // this not work
                document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = data.toString();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no access to `document` in the main process (where I suppose you have this code). You have to communicate between your processes by using IPC, code execution on HTML or even globals. (You can find lot of articles about it online)
See [`electron's architecture`](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture) for details.

An example to deal with this scenario could be

*main.js*

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  win.setMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Open File',
      click (menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({
          properties: ['openFile']
        }, (filePath) => {
          fs.readFile(filePath[0], (err, data) => {
            if (!err) {
              browserWindow.webContents.send('print-file', data.toString())
            }
        })
        })
      }
    }
  ]))
})
```

*index.html*

```js
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
      ipcRenderer.on('print-file', (event, datastr) => {
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = datastr
      })
    </script>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an environment where I can test this right now but I think your writing the `showOpenDialog` incorrectly. If you look at the [manual page](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) the first argument is an optional browser window object. It looks like your not using one so your code should be:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(null, {properties: ['openFile']}, (filePath) => {
        // read the file
        fs.readFile(filePath[0], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                // do something
                console.log('ERROR: ' + data);
            } else {
                // this not work
                console.log('PASS: ' + data);
                document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = data.toString();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

When an argument (parameter) is optional you still need to send something in. Since you don't want to use it I sent in `null` so the `showOpenDialog` function knows your not going to use it. I also added some `console.log()` so you can test your results before trying to use the `data`.

Comment: you can omit the first argument, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @pergy - Well now I have to tear apart the source code to satisfy my curiosity. I didn't know Node.js / Electron used overloading. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/ca2d74e1185626f6c9179bf0cf7382e010a49bf0/atom/common/native_mate_converters/file_dialog_converter.cc#L38 these kinda native mate dictionary getters are optional

Answer (score 0):

main.js:

```
 Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      {
        label: '&File',
        submenu: [
          {
            label: 'Open',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
            click() {
              showOpen()
            }
          },
          { type: 'separator' },
          {
            role: 'quit',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q'
          }
        ]
      }])
    
      function showOpen() {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({
          properties: ['openFile']
        }).then(result => {
          console.log(result.canceled)  // Optional
          console.log(result.filePaths) // Optional
          
          // Read first file of list (or process an array of files)
          readFile(result.filePaths[0]) 
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
    
      function readFile(filepath) {
        fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
          if(err){
            alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message)
            return
          }
          console.log(JSON.parse(data)) // For JSON file only
        })
      }
```

Instead of `console.log(JSON.parse(data))`, you process the file and then send it to the browser using, for example, [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)